# Как отсортировать по приоритетам?

Tags: android, java

Ребят, всем привет.

Есть класс Enum с такими параметрами: LOW, MIDDLE, HIGHT.

У каждой заметки записан один из этих параметров. Хочу реализовать функцию сортировки, напишу свой компоратор. Только вот подскажите, по каким критерия сортировать? Хотел заменить LOW, MIDDLE, HIGHT на 0, 1 , 2. Как бы вы поступили?

Comment: Сделал бы точно так же. Обозначил бы LOW, MIDDLE, HIGHT int константами и уже с ними бы работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum Priority {
    LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
}
```

В компараторе:

```
return java.util.Arrays.asList(Priority.values()).indexOf(lhs) - java.util.Arrays.asList(Priority.values()).indexOf(rhs);
```

P. S. *High* пишется без "**T**", средний (в контексте приоритета) - не *Middle*, а *Medium*

Answer (score 1):

Можно перечисления сделать вот так:

```
public enum Priority{
    LOW(0), MEDIUM(1), HIGH(2);

    private int ID;

    Priority(int id){
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public static Priority getByID(int id){
        switch (id){
            case 0:
                return LOW;
            case 1:
                return MEDIUM;
            case 2:
                return HIGH;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Enum not exists");
        }
    }
}
```

Дальше это все использовать так

```
int p = Priority.LOW.getID();    // p = 1
Priority priority = Priority.getByID(0);   //priority = Priority.LOW
```